# How can make my search method better in jquery?

Tags: jquery, string, search, match

i wrote very simple search method using jquery, here is my method :

```
function filter () {
    array = []
    // Search For items on Searchbox
    var name = $(this).find('.info').text().toLowerCase()
    items = name.match( $('#Search').val().toLowerCase() )

    // Select Valid items
    if ( items != null ){
        array.push(items)
        $(this).addClass('Result');
        return items;
    }
}
```

This method works very good, but the problem is the result

If we have this text

```
Enjoy your company
```

"Enjoy your" is `true` but "your Enjoy" is `false`.

How can I make my method better to fix this problem and I can catch if words are different order?

And I want if user searches for "Enjoy your z" result should be `false`

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayuryenk/3/).

Comment: It sounds like you want to split on spaces, and then test if the name contains all of those words, as separate words. Maybe split both the search and the name on spaces.

Comment: but how should i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider  [`split()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) method  to achieve this result.

You can work around the following updated code to catch even if the words are in different order.

```
     array = [];
$('#Search').keyup(function (e) {                        
     $("body").find(".info").each(function(index){
                var matchedIndexes = [];
                var name = $(this).text().toLowerCase().trim();
                var splitedArray = name.split(" "); // to split by space
                var splitedSearch =$('#Search').val().toLowerCase().trim().split(" ");   

for(var i=0;i<splitedArray.length;i++){
    if(i == 0)
    var matchedLength = 0;

   for(var j=0;j<splitedSearch.length;j++){
      if (splitedArray[i].indexOf(splitedSearch[j]) == 0){ 
          if(splitedArray.length >= splitedSearch.length && matchedIndexes.indexOf(i) == -1){
                         matchedIndexes.push(i);//To avoid search the same index even after match
                         array.push(splitedArray[i])
                         $(this).addClass('match');
                         matchedLength ++;
          }
      }
    }

    if(matchedLength < splitedSearch.length)
       $(this).removeClass('match');        
   }


            });

});// keyup
```

**Update :1**
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/egqqs3mt/2/)

**Update :2**
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/egqqs3mt/3/)

**Update :3**
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/egqqs3mt/5/)

I hope this will help you.

Comment: thank you so much for your help, everything is correct, here is just one problem and that is performance problem, in your method if i search Enjoy, it will search all fields that have enjoy word, but if i search enjoy c again it will search in all fields for enjoy c, i want it to search c character only in those fields that have enjoy, not in all other fields, can you do this for me ? thank you so much for all you've done for me, i hope i can do something for you :)

Comment: @Parsoua It is unfair of you to keep coming back to ManirajSS and adding _just one more thing_ as a question in the comments.  If you have additional questions, than [Ask a New Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) extended discussions are not for the comments they are for chat.  If ManirajSS wants to continue to help, then takes the discussion to chat.